# Error while trying to populate a JTextField from a database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

This code for some reason is throwing Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException and I can't figure out why. it is being called from an actionListener in a separate class and uses a a query that is in a different class.

The code should put the fname from the result set into the fNameIn JTextField.

```
    public void fillFieilds() throws SQLException {
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the name of the user you   want to edit");
    rset = databaseQueries.fillUserFields(name);
    addUserGUI.setfNameIn(rset.getString("fname"));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: to less code to help you. show us the stacktrace. where is databaseQueries and addUserGUI intitiated?

Comment: Yes, The JOptionPane is only taking in a name that is then passed to the fillUserFields() method which is where the query is. This part of the code works it's the addUserGUI.setfNameIn(rset.getString("fname")); that is throwing the error

Comment: the compiler should tell you the exact line, where the NullPointerException is thrown. (use error.printStackTrace()) and show us all relevant code, which comes up in that Stack.

Comment: and where you get the NPE exactly?

Comment: It's ok, I've sorted it thanks, it was just a compiler error, I had to restart Intellij